# How Spring unit testing is done with annotation based implementation

Tags: java, spring

I have been learning Spring and what I understood is that biggest advantage of Spring is that it simplifies the unit testing because of its dependency injection feature ... here is what i understood, please correct me if I am wrong - suppose I have all the beans configuration in my Spring bean XML file and all my classes under `src` folder, now if I want to do unit testing (stand alone or through junit) then I will inject the test classes (having test data) into the main classes by having a Spring bean configuration file defined for my test classes.

Now, where I am confused is how I am going to achieve same when instead of having Spring XML based bean configuration I am having annotation based configuration. Suppose in my class if I have used `@Autowired` for `com.abc.TestData` which is under `src` folder then Spring will always inject the `TestData` object from `src` folder, even if I create `test` folder and there I create `com.abc.TestData_jUnit` then also I will not be able to inject this object.

So, does it mean that Spring's advantage of simplified unit testing fades when annotations are used instead of Spring bean XML file? I am quite sure that is not the case, so need your help to understand the things better.

Comment: How do you differentiate the instance injected in test and production using XML? How is this any different using annotations?

Comment: My understanding is that during testing I will have a different Spring bean XML file which will have test classes injected into main class of `src` folder and during production the main Spring bean XML file will be there which will inject real classes. Now, how this will work with annotation is what I am not clear on.

Comment: If your `TestData` is in your test sources, how would classpath scanning ever pick it up in production; for example?

Comment: Right, it will not pick up in prod. It will work only when I am unit testing. So, I will have my main test class which will create the object of main application class and then inject the test data objects. No?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to use **Constructor DI** instead of **Setter DI**. Instead of annotating your individual `private` fields as `@Autowired`, annotate the constructor instead. Spring will fill in the required beans as necessary (using `@Named` to resolve any ambiguity between beans with identical types).

Then, in your unit tests, declare a `setup()` method annotated with `@Before`, and explicitly create the object being tested, supplying whatever parameters you want into the constructor - basically doing the same thing Spring would have done had you let it dynamically create it. Of course, the values you pass into the construct can themselves be injected into your unit test class using `@Autowired` on their field declarations.

Alternatively, you can use **Spring Profiles**, in combination with `@Configuration` classes to configure different bean environments depending on the execution profile, and have different concrete beans injected into your classes being tested.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your inputs. So, basically you are saying that I will have DI using constructor injection, and spring will inject the classes in real case/production scenario but for unit testing while creating the object of that class I will explcitly pass my test data class objects?